# JQueryのAjaxのJSONを取得したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQueryのAjaxでdone()を使用しています。その返り値から以下のようにJsonデータを取得しようとしているのですが、エラーがでてできません。

```html
//$.Ajax().done(function(response){
  var data = $.parseJSON(response.responseJSON);
});
```

エラー

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o  //エラー箇所localhost/:1
```

レスポンスのJSONは以下のものです。

```
{"code":900,"message":"Already existed"}
```

どうすればJSONを取り出してオブジェクトにできるのかおしえてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.done()`メソッドで使っている関数内の変数`response`には既に解析済みのJSONオブジェクトが入っています。これは`response.message`のように扱うことができます。

実行サンプル:

```js
var obj = {
  "code": 900,
  "message": "Already existed"
};

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify(obj)
    }
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    console.log("ajax done.");
    $("#code").text(response.code);
    $("#message").text(response.message);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>code</th>
      <td id="code"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>message</th>
      <td id="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="error"></div>
```

また余談ですが、質問コードに含まれる`responseJSON`はjqXHRオブジェクトのプロパティに存在します。これを利用すれば以下のような書き方もできます。

```
$.ajax(...)
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data === jqXHR.responseJSON); //-> true
  });
```

参考リンク: http://js.studio-kingdom.com/jquery/ajax/ajax#3

Answer (score 4):

`responseJSON`にはJSONの文字列ではなく、`$.parseJSON`で解析済みのオブジェクトが格納されます。つまり`responseJSON`をそのまま使えばよく、`$.parseJSON`は不要です。

Comment: 回答有難うございます。
`data.responseJSON.message`で参照しましたが`Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`がでてしまいました。Chormeのツールで`data.responseJSON`を表示すると`Object {code: 900, message: "Already existed"}`と表示されました。

Comment: `data.responseJSON.message`ではなく`response.responseJSON.message`ではないでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、コメントを間違えました。しかし、`response.responseJSON.message`でも同じエラーがでました。

Comment: デバッガで`responseJSON`の中身を表示できていればアクセスできると思うのですが、どこが問題なのかちょっと分かりません。その状況を再現できるようなものがあればよいのですが...

Answer (score 1):

既に指摘されていて解決していそうなものですが何か引っかかる部分があるようで。
とりあえず`response.responseJSON`には期待しているオブジェクト（JSONをパースしたもの）が格納されています。

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o  //エラー箇所localhost/:1

このエラーは`response.responseJSON`を文字列化した結果`"[object Object]"`を再度parseJOSN()した際のエラーと思われます。（`[]`を見つけて配列と解釈したが o が出現するのはおかしい）

---

> Chormeのツールでdata.responseJSONを表示するとObject {code: 900, message: "Already existed"}と表示されました。

とのことで正しくパースもなされているはずです。後はアクセスできないのは変数名が間違っているか、変数のスコープ外か、といったところでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

すでに別の回答もあるのですが、サーバで正しくContent-Typeを設定すればdone()にパースされたオブジェクトが渡ってくるので自分でパースする必要はありません。jQueryはパースに失敗するとfail()を呼ぶのでエラー処理していないと何が起きたかわかりません。
サーバ側のプログラムを見直す必要があると思われます。
JSONのContent-Typeは`Application/json`です